# hadoop job -list deprecated

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning hadoop using cloudera single node vm and I got through this line

```
hadoop job -list
```

I got a warning (Use of this script to execute mapred command is deprecated. Instead use the mapred command for it.)
I'm aware that using it will work fine but I am a bit lost. Isn't mapred the old version of mapreduce?
Is it the job (class ?) that is deprecated ?
sorry for the ignorance.
what is the best way to do list the running jobs?

A link or a reference would be highly appreciated.
EDIT
If the syntax is `hadoop job [GENERIC_OPTIONS] [-submit <job-file>] | [-status <job-id>] | [-counter <job-id> <group-name> <counter-name>] | [-kill <job-id>] | [-events <job-id> <from-event-#> <#-of-events>] | [-history [all] <jobOutputDir>] | [-list [all]] | [-kill-task <task-id>] | [-fail-task <task-id>] | [-set-priority <job-id> <priority>]` then why is it deprecated? Am I missing something?

Comment: [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#job) should help

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit, I do not understand what is wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well here's the thing,

hadoop old version that supports mapred has this (hadoop job -list) command. [old command list](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#job)

and new version of hadoop does not support this functionality because of YARN. [new command list](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#job)

i think this command was available till 2.4 but from 2.6 they have removed it.( judging from the manuals)

Answer (score 1):

As I have just come across this question, and its only
answer, which left me confused, I thought I should point
out that the answer to these bits of the question

> Isn't mapred the old version of mapreduce?
>    Is it the job (class ?) that is deprecated ?

is that it is the use of `hadoop` itself in `hadoop job -list` that is
deprecated.

So the correct invocation is now

```
mapred job -list
```